# Screen capture of windows media player version 12

Tags: screen-capture, windows-media-player, bitblt

I'm trying to capture the video which is being played in windows media player(version 12) in windows 7. Bitblt method returns black screen for the video while all other windows(media controls, playlists etc.,) are captured successfully. So I browsed about this problem. One of the frequent answers is to disable video overlays in the player. I didn't find any overlay option available in the wmplayer. Also I unchecked

> "Turn on DirectX video acceleration for wmv files"

option. Then also, I'm getting black screen only. Is there any way to capture the video content in wmplayer in windows7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't happen. Try through DirectX hooking.